# JNI: write into Java array given by parameter

Tags: java-native-interface

I have the following JNI function:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_kuku_myProj_myClass
      (JNIEnv *env, jclass java_class, jbyteArray byte_array, jcharArray char_array) {


}
```

I want to write characters into the actual `jcharArray` passed to my function. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-013/

where you can take a look at: `(*env)->ReleaseBooleanArrayElements(env, array, body, mode)` with different modes of change acceptance.

```
/* release body when you decide it is no longer needed
    Pass changes back to Java */
(*env)->ReleaseCharArrayElements(env, array, body, JNI_COMMIT);
```

Hope that helps.